# How to pass multiple name value pairs to an SQL file using vsql -v from a bash script?

Tags: command-line, vertica, vsql

How to pass multiple parameters to a SQL file using `vsql` command line option?

The following is working with asingle argument:

```
/vsql -h${SERVER} -U${USER} -w${PWD} -A -t -P fieldsep=, -f test.sql -v date1="'"${FIRSTDAY}"'" > test.csv
```

But I also want to pass last date:

```
/vsql -h${SERVER} -U${USER} -w${PWD} -A -t -P fieldsep=, -f test.sql -v date1="'"${FIRSTDAY}"'" date2="'"${LASTDAY}"'" > test.csv
```

but this throws an error:

> Database "date2='20160131'" does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply repeat the `-v` option as many times as needed:

```
vsql -h${SERVER} -U${USER} -w${PWD} -A -t -P fieldsep=, -f test.sql \
-v date1="'"${FIRSTDAY}"'" -v date2="'"${LASTDAY}"'" > test.csv
```